# Progress icon while POST request is processing

Tags: html, ajax, forms, post, request

There are next initial conditions:

**Backend**: servlet for file uploading;

**UI**: form, that submits servlet for file upload:

```
<iframe id="uploadFrame" name="uploadFrame"></iframe>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" target="uploadFrame" 
      action="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/uploadFile?
      portletId=${portletId}&remoteFolder=${remoteFolder}">
...
</form>
```

When submit button for this form is clicked, that **file uploading** is in **progress** and **POST request** correspondingly is **processing** (may track in FireBug).

***Is it possible to draw progress icon dependently on this POST request is processing?***

I mean,that if POST is processing, that web page should show progress .gif icon.

Perhaps,it's possible with *Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater* function of Prototype lib or some other solution?

Anyway, looks like, it's impossible to do without ajax.

Thanks fo any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like Prototype or JQuery might have a cleaner solution, but in plain old javascript it should be possible to control the visibility of a progress icon based on the form submission (or add a new progress icon to the DOM. Here's a quick example. You'd probably want to clean this up a bit in the real world to avoid ugly stuff like inline styles:

**Parent.htm**

```
<script language="javascript">
   function ShowProgress() {
       document.getElementById("progress").style.display = "inline";
   }

   function HideProgress() {
       document.getElementById("progress").style.display = "none";
   }
</script>

<img src="progress.gif" id="progress" style="display: none"/>
<iframe id="uploadFrame" name="uploadFrame"></iframe>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="showProgress" method="post" target="uploadFrame" >
   ...
</form>
```

**SubmitResponse.htm (the page your upload form submits to)**

```
<script language="javascript">
  if (parent.HideProgress) {
     parent.HideProgress();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: and the question about, when the "HideProgress()" function will be triggered, how it will now that POST is finished,i.e. file have been uploaded? "ShowProgress()" looks OK.

thank you.

Comment: The idea is that the call to HideProgress() is on the results page of the submission, which wont' be displayed to the user until the file has been posted successfully. Alternatively, you could periodically check the readystate of the iframe using setInterval for a similar result.

Answer (score 3):

In a previous project I used jQuery to attach a late bound load handler to the iframe *after* it had been loaded and *before* the ajax post.

```
// iframe configured

// call dopost func

function dopost() {
    //this dosnt work, its for illustration that you need to wrap the iframe
    var iframe = $('iframe');
    //setup a callback to remove the gif when postback is done 
    iframe.load(function(){
      //cleanup progress indicator
    });

    //inject your animated progress gif

    //start the submit and wait for callback
    form.submit();
}
```

Once the postback is completed your callback function takes care of tearing down the gif.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice link to you: http://pixeline.be/experiments/jqUploader/